# Cut, Copy, and paste in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a lot of textboxes. I have a button that will cut the selected text of the Focused textbox. How do i do that? I have tried this:

```
        if (((TextBox)(pictureBox1.Controls[0])).SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            ((TextBox)(pictureBox1.Controls[0])).Cut();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through the controls to find the one with selected text:

```
foreach (Control x in this.PictureBox1.Controls)
{
    if (x is TextBox)
    {
        if (((TextBox)x).SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            ((TextBox)(x).Cut(); // Or some other method to get the text.
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

Hope it is WinForms

```
var textboxes = (from textbox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                    where textbox.SelectedText != string.Empty
                    select textbox).FirstOrDefault();
if (textboxes != null)
{
    textboxes.Cut();
}
```

Comment: i have many textboxes, but one button will Cut the selected text in the focused textbox's text.

Comment: You may need to loop through the textbox controls and if the textbox is focused, then do it.

Comment: will you please give me an example of a loop i will use and how to find the selectedtextBox. Thanks!

Comment: var textboxes = from textbox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                            where textbox.Focused
                            select textbox;

Answer (score 1):

Try using  common `Enter` and `Leave` events to set the last TextBox that had Focus.

```
private void textBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    focusedTextBox = null;
}

private void textBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    focusedTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(focusedTextBox == null))
    {
        if (focusedTextBox.SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(focusedTextBox.SelectedText);
            focusedTextBox.SelectedText = "";
            focusedTextBox = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I have 10 textboxes, I need to wire all the textbox controls with the events right? Seems complex :(

Comment: @Anuraj Just select the same handler in your winforms property editor for each textbox shouldn't take anytime at all. I have used common event handlers in forms having 100 or more textbox's. It helps keep the size of the code down.